# ANT to launch Java App with JNI library

Tags: java, ant, java-native-interface

I have the following **ant** target to run my Java application with **JNI call**. I was able to run the application via my **run.sh** file (in Linux). I always get **java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError** on **ant**.

My library, a wrapper, is linked with another library, **libB**. It seems it cannot find the **libB** which is under **./JNI/mtflib/lib** directory. It is on the path I provided.

I tried the "**:**"  ,  "**;**"  and  "**,**" separators for the path.
I tried the **jvmarg value="-Djava.library.path=** and "**sysproperty key="java.library.path" path=**" options. The **fork** is set to true.

```
<target name="run" depends="echo, copyLogViewer" 
        description="Run application from development environment">
        <java classname="${program.main}"
              classpathref="compile.classpath"
              fork="true">
            <jvmarg value="-Xmx${MAX_MEMORY}m"/>
            <jvmarg value="-Xms${MIN_MEMORY}m"/>
            <jvmarg value="-XX:NewSize=${YOUNG_MEMORY}m"/>
            <arg value="-v"/>
            <jvmarg value="-splash:resources/images/splash/splash.gif"/>
            <!--jvmarg value="-Djava.library.path=.:./JNI:./JNI/mtflib:./JNI/mtflib/lib:./JNI/mtflib/parse:${java.library.path}"/-->
            <sysproperty key="java.library.path" path=".:./JNI:./JNI/mtflib:./JNI/mtflib/lib:./JNI/mtflib/parse:${java.library.path}"/>
        </java>
    </target>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use this:

```
<env key="LD_LIBRARY_PATH" path="..."/>
```

Instead of above **java.library.path** ...

at least in Linux systems